# Adjust Image properties (Like change contrast, brightness etc) using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

How to perform image manipulations using NDK?
I have already set up the NDK and have done a lot of research on the topic but did not get any result.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2):

For a quick start I would recommend [Craig Lindley's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471543772)  (Practical image processing in C). The image (bitmap) is nothing more than a 2D array of bytes (actually represented as an 1D-array). You may manipulate individual pixels to achieve brightness/contrast adjustment.

Build the histogram, recalculate new values for the image (to adjust constract).

If you don't want to read any book, look for tutorials like this: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/histgram.htm  and read about it [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization)